# Mount root filesystem as R/W

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, twrp, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I use NOTE4 N910C with Android 6.0.1 PDA N910CXXU2DPE6, CSC N910COXA2DPE1 + TWRP + root, dated Wed, 11 May 2016.
All works perfectly but in this version of firmware, root filesystem is mounted as read-only. Developer mode is turn on. 
I try to remount /system from console, from ES Explorer, from Root Explorer and so on. Nothing helps. Can anybody advice me how to make root filesys as R/W. Just for a while, to make some changes.

Comment: Have you tried from a shell (e.g. `adb shell`) with root access (`su`) to run `mount -o remount,rw /system`? Does it work, or give an error? In the latter case, which error exactly? "Nothing helps" is not very specific, as we don't know what happens unless you [edit] your question and include the errors you're seeing :)

Comment: Yes,. Of course I used mount -o remount,rw /system as su. The command was executed without any error but root filesys was still read only.

Comment: "No error but no effect" sounds strange. Not sure if that's some SELinux enforcement (or something comparable), but I'd expect an error if something doesn't work.

Comment: It was possible to access as R/W root files in ver 5.1.1 and in first version of in 6.0.1. After upgrade to new verion of 6.0.1 - R/W access is not possible. Terrible...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I remount /system as R/W. The proper syntax of command is:

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

NOT:

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

I really dont know why, but second syntax is executed without errors but /system is still read only. The first command works on NOTE 4 N910C correctly.
Thats all, topic closed.